# Does it make sense to have input parameters to a class?

Tags: java

I created a class of DocumentFilter type as follows:

```
public class CustomDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter
    {
        private StyledDocument styledDocument;
        private JTextPane panetxt;

        public CustomDocumentFilter(JTextPane panetxt) {
            this.panetxt = panetxt; // Not really necessary
            this.styledDocument = panetxt.getStyledDocument();
        } 

        private final StyleContext styleContext = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();

        Pattern pattern = buildPattern(mystring);



        private Pattern buildPattern(String mystring)
        {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] toke = StringUtils.split(mystring,",");

        for (String token : toke) {
            sb.append("\\b"); 
            sb.append(token);
        }
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); 
        }

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());

        return p;
        }
```

My question is: how to include `mystring` within the call of CustomDocumentFilter?:

```
//String mystring="lalala";
((AbstractDocument) editeur.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CustomDocumentFilter(editeur));
```

EDIT:

Regarding the first way Jonathan suggests, I get this:

```
error: cannot find symbol Pattern pattern = buildPattern(mystring); ^ symbol: variable mystring location: class TextEditor.CustomDocumentFilter
```

I don't know if it has to do with the Pattern clause

Comment: You could add one more parameter to the constructor.. And as long as you get your desired result in the most efficient way there is no problem in adding a parameter to a constructor..

Comment: If you're not using the `JTextPane` for anything else than getting the `StyledDocument` out of there, why don't you just accept a `StyledDocument` as the parameter?

Comment: What's `mystring`? Where does it come from? What does it contain?

Comment: The thing is that I need an input parameter for buildPattern(); and I don't know how to pass it. How could it be added to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what is desired from the description.  But I think your simply trying to ask how to get your local string value into your new CustomDocumentFilter object.

Well that is simple and you have choices!  More than the two I show here.
first easy way is to add it to the constructor

```
public CustomDocumentFilter(JTextPane panetxt, String myString) {
  ...
  pattern = buildPattern(mystring);
}

((AbstractDocument) editeur.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CustomDocumentFilter(editeur, myString));
```

another way is to use a method that returns the object

```
public CustomDocumentFilter myFunction(String myString) {
  pattern = buildPattern(mystring);
  return this;
}

((AbstractDocument) editeur.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CustomDocumentFilter(editeur).myFunction(myString));
```

Comment: Regarding the first way to do it, I get this:

error: cannot find symbol
     Pattern pattern = buildPattern(mystring);
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable mystring
  location: class TextEditor.CustomDocumentFilter

I don't know if it has to do with the  Pattern clause

Comment: if you can add the more of the code I could determine what is wrong.  My example assumed you make Pattern pattern a field of the class like you did styledDocument and panetxt